# Sintaxe de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro:

```
UPDATE clientes SET 
txtEndereco=\"Rua XingÃº, 823\", 
txtBairro=\"Val ParaÃ­so\", 
txtCEP=\"09060-050\", 
txtUF=\"35\",
txtCidade=\"14933\",
regiaos=\"\",
Obs=\"Princesa fada\") 
WHERE idCliente = \"2\
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"Rua XingÃº, 823\", txtBairro=\"Val ParaÃ­so\", txtCEP=\"09060-050\", txtUF=\"3' at line 1

Comment: Para especificar valores, use sempre aspas simples!

Comment: Estava sobrando um ") antes do WHERE também... valeu man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que usar por aspas simples e não precisa necessariamente escapar elas, a não ser que a palavra tenha em sua string o caracter das aspas.

```
UPDATE clientes SET 
txtEndereco = 'Rua Xingú, 823', 
txtBairro = 'Val Paraí­so', 
txtCEP = '09060-050', 
txtUF = 35,
txtCidade = '14933',
regiaos = '',
Obs = 'Princesa fada'
WHERE idCliente = 2
```